# Python Twisted asynchronous scheduling without blocking

Tags: python, json, multithreading, asynchronous, twisted

Sorry for the title, but not sure how to describe what I am trying to do in a single sentence. Basically each object I have is fast enough to not block when created 1 at a time, but if I have a dozen or hundreds, then it blocks the main loop. I am trying to find a way to reduce the amount of stuttering occurring when loading objects. Essentially the application I have has to render every frame and if anything longer than a frame, the application starts appearing jittery.

The main problem is that when I create objects, they have to lookup data from a json file and import it. Now each json file itself is pretty quick (0.006s) which is faster than 1/60 of a frame. However, it becomes an issue when the counter starts becoming x*0.006.

What's interesting is if I use something like deferToThread it still blocks the main loop. Here is what I am trying to do. I want the objects available instantly, because having them done instantly is very important. However the actual json loading is less important, I'd like to have it somehow schedule it so the others start to 'fill in' so to speak as they become available. The order in which they are available is also unnecessary.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from profilehooks import profile
import json

objects = []

def print_test(text):
    print text

class JsonObject(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
        self.json_data = None
        self.load() # <load data slowly somehow?>
        # Threads not working either?
        #d = threads.deferToThread(self.load)
        #d.addCallback(self.set_json_data)

    def load(self):
        with open("{0}.json".format(str(self.i).zfill(3))) as f:
            self.json_data = json.load(f)
        #return self.json_data


    def set_json_data(self, data):
        print "GOT DATA", self.i

def load_objects():
    for i in xrange(300):
        objects.append(JsonObject(i))

    print "LOADED ALL OBJECTS"

reactor.callLater(0, load_objects)
reactor.callLater(0.5, print_test, "test for blocking")
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Tried reactor.callLater(0.1, self.load())?

Comment: Tried that as well, same result.

Comment: I am sorry, it is so late here now and I can't think about anything useful now... I usually put something which I don't want to interfere with main program to subprocess. Did you think about that?

Answer (score 0):

Basically `for i in xrange(300)` is blocking your main reactor. Here's an easy way to take small breaks in your `load_objects` function and return control to the reactor/event loop so other tasks can get done.

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def load_objects():
    for i in xrange(300):
        objects.append(JsonObject(i))

        if i % 100 == 0:
            yield    # take a break and let reactor do other tasks

        print("LOADED ALL OBJECTS")
```

There's also the the [`cooperate`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.task.html#cooperate) function that does something similar, but I've always found `inlineCallbacks` to be more intuitive.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, yes I realize that the example I provided will block because of the amount of objects. It blocks it because of the `self.load()` the object does on init.If I remove the `self.load` it will load instantly. What I want to do is load all JsonObject (because by themselves they are fast without the load function on init), but have it so each one has scheduled a call to self.load that will be 'spread out' so to speak so that it does not block.

Comment: That's what this answer does.  It's also what cooperate() would do.  The difference with cooperate() (which makes it better) is that it does time-based work chunks instead of hard-coding some number (which may be too many - giving you stuttering - or too few - making the process take longer.

Comment: Also, deferToThread should work fine if you use it right.  You didn't post any code that uses deferToThread so it's hard to say what you might have done wrong.

Comment: This only spreads it out **if** I am going to be calling them in an xrange, or IF the creation technique is used as an iterator, which it will not be. Ignore that. The only reason I even have xrange is for the smallest example to show how it does block. What I am looking for is that even if I create 300 objects, no matter how, no matter in which way, it does not block.  The non-blocking has to come from within the object itself, not in the manner the object is created. My example does have a defer to thread example (commented out) which does not work either.

Comment: If I recall correctly opening of files is a synchronous task and there's not much Python or other language can do about it. This has to do with how the OS handles files at a low level. With that aside how are 300+ JSON files opened each frame? And to add to that, if you're opening that many files per tick, it may be best to devise some sort of caching mechanism because, as you've noticed, it's very inefficient to open a large number of files at once. You could also speed up JSON loads via C module or a package like `python-cjson`, although it won't really affect the overall app speed too much

Comment: That's fine if I just have to load one json at a time. Ideally what I'd like is that I'd create all of the base objects (in this case JsonObject), then for each object schedule `self.load` one by one like a queue, while notifying the object. I don't mind waiting for each to complete slowly, just as long as its not blocking. And this example using 300 objects was just to illustrate the issue of blocking without a GUI render. Even with 3 objects loading you are still skipping frames in a 60 FPS application (3*0.006), you just can't tell without rendering frames.